# Sorting procedure doesn't work

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

I'm trying to sort a column of 7 values starting in cell A40, and ending in A46. I am using a bubble sort and I create two procedure. However, when I execute, VBA tells me the subscript is out of range... Would anyone be able to tell me where is the problem in my code, please?

```
Sub dort()

    Dim plaga() As Variant
    plaga = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A40:A46").Value


    Call tri1(plaga)

    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C40")
    Destination.Resize(7, 1).Value = plaga

End Sub

Sub tri1(plaga As Variant)


    Dim ligne_Deb As Long
    Dim ligne_Fin As Long

    ligne_Deb = LBound(plaga)
    ligne_Fin = UBound(plaga)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tmp As Long

        For i = ligne_Deb To ligne_Fin - 1
        For j = ligne_Fin To i + 1 Step -1
            If plaga(j) < plaga(j - 1) Then
            tmp = plaga(j)
            plaga(j) = plaga(j - 1)
            plaga(j - 1) = tmp
            End If
        Next j
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: why you sort this way instead of using Excel built-in `Sort` object? keep in mind that your procedure is inefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would anyone be able to tell me where is the problem in my code, please?

```
plaga = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A40:A46").Value
```

When you store range in an array, it is not a single dimension array.

Change your code to

```
plaga(j,1)
```

Notice the `,1`. Incorporate that every where.

For example

```
For i = ligne_Deb To ligne_Fin - 1
    For j = ligne_Fin To i + 1 Step -1
        If plaga(j, 1) < plaga(j - 1, 1) Then
            tmp = plaga(j, 1)
            plaga(j, 1) = plaga(j - 1, 1)
            plaga(j - 1, 1) = tmp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

[Interesting read](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: I just tested the code and it works just fine. Replace your FOR loop with my FOR loop

Comment: Could you just please tell me why the array is not one-dimension even if I took a range than it composed of several rows but just one column?

Comment: See the link that I added at the bottom of my post ;)

Comment: Gr8 :) Now the main question. Why bubble sort and not the Excel's inbuilt sort? Is your data stored as alpha numeric data?

Comment: No, I would have liked to use an excel inbuilt sort, but I am required to write the algorithm myself, as it is for a project...

Comment: But I think I will try that one too later on :) to add variety.

Comment: You might find this link interesting too ;) http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?473677-VB6-Sorting-algorithms-%28sort-array-sorting-arrays%29